# Facebook Open graph Api - Events maybe_count stopped working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

hi I just noticed that the fields `maybe_count` and `declined_count` for Events stopped working. They return 0 instead of the correct values. Did anyone else experience the same problem ? has the API been changed?

I used to use this query inside my PHP script:

`"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/".$fb_eventID."?fields=attending_count,declined_count,maybe_count&".$accessToken;`

Answer (score 0):

wow, seems like it is not called `maybe_count` anymore but `interested_count` . Just replace it and it should work fine again.